Brownian Motion: Confusion Between Probability and Conditional Probability
When we study a Brownian Motion:
$$X_t = \mu t + \epsilon_t$$
$$\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2 t)$$
This means that each Xt is independently (but not identically) distributed as:
$$X_t \sim N(\mu t, \sigma^2 t)$$
So, the probability distribution for each Xt can be written as:
$$P(X_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2 t}} \exp\left(-\frac{(X_t - \mu t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\right)$$
I am wondering, can we write this same model in terms of conditional probability (i.e. probability of current point conditional on previous point)?
I first wrote $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$:
$$X_{t-1} = \mu (t-1) + \epsilon_{t-1}$$
$$X_t = \mu t + \epsilon_t$$
To find $X_t|X_{t-1}$, I wrote the increment:
$$X_t - X_{t-1} = [\mu t + \epsilon_t] - [\mu (t-1) + \epsilon_{t-1}]$$
$$                = \mu + (\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1})$$
Now for the errors. I think that $\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1}$ is the difference of two independent normal variables:
$$\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2 t)$$
$$\epsilon_{t-1} \sim N(0, \sigma^2 (t-1))$$
Since these are a Normal Distributions, the differences of these should be normally distributed:
$$\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1} \sim N(0, \sigma^2 t + \sigma^2 (t-1)) = N(0, \sigma^2 (2t-1))$$
Therefore, I think the conditional distribution is:
$$X_t | X_{t-1} \sim N[X_{t-1} + \mu, \sigma^2 (2t-1)]$$
To wrap things up:
$$P(X_t | X_{t-1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2 (2t-1)}} \exp\left(-\frac{(X_t - (X_{t-1} + \mu))^2}{2\sigma^2 (2t-1)}\right)$$
Is my understanding of this correct?

Potential Correction?
Define:
$$X_t = \mu t + \epsilon_t$$
$$\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2 t)$$
This means that each $X_t$ is independently (but not identically) distributed as:
$$X_t \sim N(\mu t, \sigma^2 t)$$
So, the probability distribution for each $X_t$ can be written as:
$$P(X_t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2 t}} \exp\left(-\frac{(X_t - \mu t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\right)$$
To write in terms of conditional probability (i.e., probability of the current point conditional on the previous point), we can express $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$:
$$X_{t-1} = \mu (t-1) + \epsilon_{t-1}$$
$$X_t = \mu t + \epsilon_t$$
To find $X_t|X_{t-1}$, we write:
$$X_t - X_{t-1} = [\mu t + \epsilon_t] - [\mu (t-1) + \epsilon_{t-1}]$$
$$                = \mu + (\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1})$$
Now, for the conditional distribution of $\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1}$ given $X_{t-1}$:
$$\epsilon_{t-1} = X_{t-1} - \mu(t-1)$$
Therefore:
$$(\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1})|X_{t-1} \sim N(-X_{t-1} + \mu(t-1), \sigma^2 t)$$
This means that the conditional distribution of $X_t$ given $X_{t-1}$ is:
$$X_t|X_{t-1} \sim N(\mu t, \sigma^2 t)$$
This is exactly the same as the unconditional distribution of $X_t$, which is consistent with the fact that each $X_t$ is independently distributed.
Therefore:
$$P(X_t | X_{t-1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2 t}} \exp\left(-\frac{(X_t - \mu t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\right)$$

Who defines a “random walk” this way? Especially the part where the $X_t$ are independent.

@farrow90: As David K pointed out, the standard way to write the RW is $x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$. You are on the right track though as far as writing the density of $x_t$ using $x_{t-1}$. But it's easier to do that if you remember $x_{t} - x_{t-1}$ is independent and normal with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. Look in Schilling's Brownian motion text. All of this is covered in there. Me trying to write it all here won't be useful.

As mentioned in the comment, $X_{t}$ is not a random walk in your case. Even following your definition, your derivation is still incorrect.
$X_{t}=X_{t-1}+\mu+(\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{t-1})$, the first part $X_{t-1}+\mu$ given $X_{t-1}$ is itself. So far so good. In the next step, you should find out the conditional distribution of $\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{t-1}$ given $X_{t-1}$ instead of the unconditional one you derived above.
Do you have information about $\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{t-1}$ given $X_{t-1}$? Sure, because $\epsilon_{t-1}=X_{t-1}-\mu(t-1)$. So $(\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{t-1})|X_{t-1}\sim\mathcal{N}(-X_{t-1}+\mu(t-1),\sigma^{2}t)$, and hence the conditional mean of $X_{t}$ is $X_{t-1}+\mu-X_{t-1}+\mu(t-1)=\mu t$ and $X_{t}|X_{t-1}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu t,\sigma^{2}t)$, i.e., exactly coincide with the unconditional distribution.
Not surprisingly, since you noticed in the second sentence "This means that each Xt is independently (but not identically) distributed..."
P.S. Given the special variance structure, I suppose you were intended to assume $\epsilon$ is a Brownian motion. If this is the case, $X_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ are no longer independent, and note that $X_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_{t-1}$ generate the same sigma algebra hence $\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}$ given $X_{t-1}$ is standard Gaussian.

Thank you for your answer! Based on your comments, I added an update to my question to try and correct it. To begin with, after what you wrote, I think the process I defined is a Brownian Motion and not a Random Walk. I have tried to rewrite the conditional probability distribution ... can you please take a look at what I wrote? much appreciated ...

@farrow90 The updated conditional distribution is correct (under the original assumption that $\epsilon_{t}$ and $\epsilon_{t-1}$ are independent). And if instead your $\epsilon$ is Brownian motion, then yes, $X_{t}$ is a Brownian motion but with drift $\mu$.
